# What graphics drivers do you use?

Tags: 14.04, ati, graphics

What graphics drivers do you guys use nvidia/amd proprietary on opensource and why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the latest proprietary NVIDIA -updates driver shown in the Driver Manager instead of the X.Org X server Nouveau driver. In my system Linux installed, the keyboard was not working when it is resumed from Sleep/Suspend when using Nouveau. With the proprietary driver this problem does not occur.